# TableView section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to design a dynamic table which has 2 sections, first section has 4 cells and second one has 41 cells. I want to program these 2 sections separately but I can only modify one section. how can I modify each section separately. The codes that I wrote so far is like this:

```
{
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

        return 2;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (section == 0)
            return 4;
        else
            return 41;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Questions";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Questions"];

        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question %lu", (unsigned long)indexPath.row +1];

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSIndexPath has both a row property and a section property.  From these two properties, you can tell which cell you are currently working on in

- `<(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

For example:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Questions";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Questions"];

        if (indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1st Group - Question %d", indexPath.row + 1];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2nd Group - Question %d", indexPath.row + 1];
        }

        return cell;
    }
```